# Why can't INQUIRY statements be used inside PURE procedures

Tags: io, fortran, fortran90

I see that `INQUIRE` statements are not allowed inside `PURE` procedures. Why is this case? Isn't the `INQUIRE` statement free of any side-effects and therefore is itself `PURE`?

Comment: Hmmm. Fair enough. Make this into an answer and I'll mark this as closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't pretend to have any insight into the workings of the language standards committee or its members so this is my reading of the situation:

Inquire statements may be free of side-effects in the sense that they don't cause any change of state, but the same inquire statement executed twice doesn't guarantee to give the same answer. Another process might, perhaps, delete a file between inquiries. It's (perhaps) a more subtle impurity, but an impurity nonetheless.

Comment: According to the Fortran 95 Handbook "input/output is generally considered to be a side effect"; and the later section on "Rules and restrictions" section explicitly lists `INQUIRE` as impure. As you say, repeated calls may not yield the same result so if purity is intended to ensure reproducability, `INQUIRE` fails. Which is sort of a shame since certain forms of impurity shouldn't matter (e.g. diagnostic logging)